# Holoviews Sankey Diagram specify node and edge ordering

Tags: python, holoviews

I've got a Bokeh app with multiple Holoviews Sankey diagrams controlled via some Bokeh widget inputs.

The Sankey diagrams are based on data stored in pandas DataFrames, which contain the same categories for all diagrams, except that the value for each category is different.

Every time I update the Sankey diagram the nodes (and the edge coloring) switches around. Is it possible somewhere to define the order of the nodes and edges so that they stay the same for all diagrams?